# Regular expression not returning the .group() value

Tags: java, regex

I'm new with java and using regular expressions. The method seems to be OK, and it's finding results on the subject string, but when I try to get the actual string using .group(), it's empty. here's the code:

```
public String TestRegularExpression(){
    try{
      Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(pattern, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE);
      Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(sourceCode);
      while (regexMatcher.find()) {
        results += "<li>" + regexMatcher.group() + "</li>";
        matches ++;
      } 
    } catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
      results = "<li><strong class='ibm-important'>Syntax error in the regular expression</strong></li>";
    }

    if(results == null){results = "<li><strong class='ibm-important'>No meta tags found</strong></li>";}
    return "<h3>" + h3Title + " (" + matches + " found)</h3><ul>" + results + "</ul>";
  }
```

Any help will be much appreciated!!!

Comment: It'd be useful for you to include what `pattern` is defined as...

Comment: Hard to know what's wrong based on the scraps of information that you're giving us. We need to know pattern and a sample of sourceCode String. Best of all would be for you to create and post an [sscce](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Amber, here's the pattern: "<meta.*?name=\".*?\".*?>" and the subject string is a page source code with meta tags. In fact, the page has 19 meta tags and groupCount is returning all 19 matches. =(

Comment: Doesn't `.group()` require that you have a `()` somewhere in your regex?

Comment: Further information. The method is printing out "Meta tags (19 found)" on my Servlet, so the regex and the iteration seems to be working just fine, the only issue I have is that I can't get the match string value from it.

Comment: @glowcoder: Nope. You use `.group(int)` to fetch the value of parenthesized subexpressions. The argument-less `.group()` fetches the value of the entire matched string.

Comment: As a side-issue, it would seem more prudent to compile the regex in static code ("static Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(...)") instead of doing it on every invocation. Not only does it make the invocation cheaper, but you also don't have to handle the syntax-error exception in the runtime code.

Comment: @DiegoSagrera - Please update your question with the needed information instead of putting it in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't it be that you're just not seeing the output? If you output the match directly to HTML without quoting it, that'll just insert the META tag in the HTML code, and the web browser won't render it.

Comment: Oh geez, what a silly mistake from me. Here's the fixed line for dumbs like me:

results += "<li>" + (regexMatcher.group()).replaceAll("<", "&lt;").replaceAll(">", "&gt;") + "</li>";